# Returning a decimal value in JSON via a vb/asp.net 2.0 WebMethod, how can I make it a number and not a string?

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

For example:

the calling party wants:

```
"amount" : 1234.56
```

but I'm sending:

```
"amount" : "1234.56"
```

I'm using a vb.net to write an asp.net (2.0) WebMethod, using a class to build an object:

```
Public Class PriceData
    Property amount As Double
        Get
            Return m_amount
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            m_amount = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_amount As Double
    Property currency As String
        Get
            Return m_currency
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_currency = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_currency As String

End Class
```

However, the expected JSON for the "amount" field should be number and is coming over as a string instead.

BEGIN EDIT:

Here is what the WebMethod looks like:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function return_value(ByVal ItemId As String) As PriceData
    Dim test As PriceData = getPriceData(ByVal ItemId As String)
    Return test
End Function
```

The function getPriceData simple hits the database and returns the price data object, which looks like:

```
"priceData": {
    "amount": "1234.56",
    "currency": "USD"
  }
```

END EDIT

Is there anything I can do to change this value to a number?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code where you generate the JSON

Comment: Technically I don't generate the JSON, vb/asp.net returns WebMethod calls as JSON. I'll edit my question to include the WebMethod.